# SQL: counting set elements after truncation

Tags: sql, count, set, truncate

```
select THING from FOLDER where THING like '%-%' and ...
```

which returns things like:

```
abc097-01
def982-02
ghi13344-01
ghi13344-02
```

Now I need to change this query so that I can count distinct names, after truncating the part after the '-'.

So for the example above, I'd get 3 as a result ("abc097","def982" and "ghi13344").

How can I write that in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @tmp table (field nvarchar(100))
insert into @tmp values ('abc097-01')
insert into @tmp values ('def982-02')
insert into @tmp values ('ghi13344-01')
insert into @tmp values ('ghi13344-02')

select COUNT(*),SUBSTRING(field,0,CHARINDEX('-',field))
from @tmp
group by SUBSTRING(field,0,CHARINDEX('-',field))


select distinct(SUBSTRING(field,0,CHARINDEX('-',field)))
from @tmp -- to get distinct records.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) or [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) functions to find the location of the '-' and then use the [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) or [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) functions:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(THING, 1, PATINDEX('%-%', THING) - 1))
from FOLDER
where THING like '%-%'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm on Oracle however so PATINDEX apparently ain't working (I used INSTR and it worked :).  I was hoping there would be a standard SQL way to do this without needed SQL server or Oracle-specific queries.  Thanks again :)

Comment: @Gugussee Unfortunately, string and date functions aren't really universal.  You're right, INSTR is the equivalent in Oracle.